# Spring boot cloud config client not picking up cloud config server URI bootstrap settings?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to connect my Spring Boot app to a Cloud config server.  I have the name of the cloud config server defined in the 'bootstrap.properties' file

```
spring.application.name=eis-account
spring.profiles.active=default
spring.cloud.config,uri=http://localhost:8001
```

... but on launching the Spring Boot app it is just ignoring this and looking for

```
017-12-02 17:06:22.070  INFO 6516 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2017-12-02 17:06:23.187  WARN 6516 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/eis-account/default": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2017-12-02 17:06:23.189  INFO 6516 --- [           main] com.eis.account.EisAccountApplication    : The following profiles are active: default
2017-12-02 17:06:23.211  INFO 6516 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2c1156a7: startup date [Sat Dec 02 17:06:23 GMT 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7880cdf3
2017-12-02 17:06:24.001  INFO 6516 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=cf9b218d-4afe-3a28-b0b8-7c49b6339bdf
2017-12-02 17:06:24.135  INFO 6516 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f6e4cf3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

201

My pom file is shown below.  Any ideas?

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.eis.account</groupId>
<artifactId>eis-account</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>eis-account</name>
<description>EIS Account micro service</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `spring.cloud.config,uri` should be `spring.cloud.config.uri`, i.e. you have a comma instead of a dot.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
spring.cloud.config,uri=http://localhost:8001
```

for

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8001
```

(DOT is your error)